# Fluent NHibernate trying to change mysql table for every subclasses

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am building an application with inheritance

```cs
class A
class B : A
class C : A
class D : A
...
```

Then

```cs
public class ClassA_Map : ClassMapping<A>
{
    public ClassA_Map()
    {
        Table("tableA");
        ID(...)
        Property(...) 
    }
}
```

Now I triing change table (mysql) for Class B (C, D, ...) :

```
public class ClassB_Map : SubclassMapping<B>
{
    public ClassB_Map()
    {
        Table("tableB");
    }
}
```

But SubclassMapping does not has method Table... How I can do change tableName for class B (C, D, ...)

If set ClassB_Map constructor empty, then sql has "... FROM tableA "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented here [Fluent mapping - Subclasses](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#subclasses) you should have it like this *(see the `SubclassMap` base)*:

```
public class ClassA_Map : ClassMap<A>
{
    public ClassA_Map()
    {
        Table("tableA");
        ID(...)
        Property(...) 

public class ClassB_Map : SubclassMap<B>
{
    public ClassB_Map()
    {
        Table("tableB");
```

Also check [Fluent NHibernate - how to create table-per-subclass mapping using a discriminator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888244)